# PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator image gallery

Tags: php

Using an answer from elsewhere on SO, I am working on a basic PHP iterator to show images in nested DIRs.

My goal is to have PHP run through the DIRs and add an IMG tag with the SRC pointing to the files through which it iterates.

I am mostly there, but there are some extra characters showing up which prevent the image from displaying.

**CODE** (h2 and h3 are for readability while debugging, problem exists whether they are there or not):

```
// Create recursive dir iterator which skips dot folders
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./images/families/',
    FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

// Flatten the recursive iterator, folders come before their files
$it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

// Maximum depth is 1 level deeper than the base folder
$it->setMaxDepth(5);

// Basic loop displaying different messages based on file or folder
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
        printf("<h2>Folder - %s\n</h2>", $fileinfo->getFilename());
    } elseif ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        printf("<h3><img src=\"images/families/%s/%s></h3>", $it->getSubPath(), $fileinfo->getFilename());
    }
}
```

---

**RESULT** via view source in browser:

```
Folder - smith/40th
<img src="images/families/smith/40th/40th_1.jpg>
<img src="images/families/smith/40th/40th_11.jpg>
```

..etc

---

**RESULT** in browser window (on choosing "open image in new window"):

```
"The requested URL /images/families/smith/40th/40th_1.jpg><img src= was not found on this server.""

This is the URL in the address bar:
/images/families/smith/40th/40th_1.jpg%3E%3Cimg%20src=
```

---

So my code creating the img is adding extra characters / creating characters not read properly by the browser.

Is this an encoding issue? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed the closing quote in the `src` attribute, which is causing it to run onto the subsequent markup.

```
printf("<h3><img src=\"images/families/%s/%s\"></h3>", $it->getSubPath(), $fileinfo->getFilename());
//-----------------------------------------^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to close the image tags:

```
printf("<h2>Folder - %s\n</h2>", $fileinfo->getFilename());
} elseif ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
    printf("<h3><img src=\"images/families/%s/%s\"></h3>", $it->getSubPath(), $fileinfo->getFilename());
}
```